# Combining two queries to add additional column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two SQL queries that I want to combine into one. The 2nd should add an additional column to the 1st.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    T3.AcctCode, T3.AcctName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T0.TaxDate BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'
             THEN T1.Debit - T1.Credit 
             ELSE 0 END)* -1 AS [Balance],
    SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit)* -1  AS [YTD Balance],
    (CASE WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '611110' AND '612000'
       THEN 1 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '541100' AND '541950'
       THEN 2 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '542100' AND '542700'
       THEN 3 WHEN T3.AcctCode = '543100'
       THEN 4 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '511100' AND '511950'
       THEN 5 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '512100' AND '512995'
       THEN 6 WHEN T3.AcctCode = '513100'
       THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) AS [Group]
FROM 
    OJDT T0
INNER JOIN 
    JDT1 T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId]
INNER JOIN 
    OACT T2 ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN 
    OACT T3 ON T3.[AcctCode] = T2.[FatherNum]
WHERE 
    T0.TaxDate BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-12-31'     
    AND T2.GroupMask IN(5,6)
GROUP BY 
    T3.AcctCode, T3.AcctName
```

Sample Output

[image]

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    T1.FatherNum, SUM(T0.CredLTotal) AS [Budget]
FROM 
    OBGT T0
LEFT JOIN 
    OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
WHERE 
    T1.GroupMask IN (5, 6) 
    AND (T1.FatherNum BETWEEN '511100' AND '612000') 
    AND YEAR(T0.FinancYear) = 2015 
GROUP BY 
    T1.FatherNum
```

Sample Output

[image]

I have come up with this:

```
SELECT 
    T3.AcctCode, T3.AcctName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T0.TaxDate BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'
             THEN T1.Debit - T1.Credit 
             ELSE 0 END)* -1 AS [Balance],
    SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit)* -1  AS [YTD Balance],
    SUM(T4.CredLTotal) AS [Budget],
    (CASE WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '611110' AND '612000'
       THEN 1 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '541100' AND '541950'
       THEN 2 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '542100' AND '542700'
       THEN 3 WHEN T3.AcctCode = '543100'
       THEN 4 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '511100' AND '511950'
       THEN 5 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '512100' AND '512995'
       THEN 6 WHEN T3.AcctCode = '513100'
       THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) AS [Group]
FROM 
    OJDT T0
INNER JOIN 
    JDT1 T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId]
INNER JOIN 
    OACT T2 ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN 
    OACT T3 ON T3.[AcctCode] = T2.[FatherNum]
LEFT JOIN 
    OBGT T4 ON (T4.[AcctCode] = T2.[AcctCode] 
            AND YEAR(T4.FinancYear) = 2015)
WHERE 
    T0.TaxDate BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-12-31'     
    AND T2.GroupMask IN (5, 6)     
GROUP BY 
    T3.AcctCode, T3.AcctName, T2.FatherNum
ORDER BY 
    T3.AcctCode
```

Sample Output

[image]

However, the column `Balance` shows incorrect figures, i.e. not returning the results of the 2nd query.

How do I get `SUM(T4.CredLTotal) AS [Budget]` to sum properly?

Comment: This isn't the way to ask your question.  Instead, you should show us sample input/output with your current query attempt.  It will be very hard to decipher what the data in your tables might look like based on such complex queries.

Comment: That's a *really* confusing way to lay out your `CASE` expressions. Every `THEN` clause corresponds to the immediately preceding `WHEN` clause, but you've lined them up with the *succeeding* `WHEN` clauses, which are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into details of these complex queries, it looks like you want to simply join two queries together.

In the first query you group by `AcctCode, AcctName`. I assume that result will have one row per `AcctCode`, i.e. `AcctCode` will not repeat in the result set.

In the second query you group by `FatherNum`, so it will not repeat in the result set as well.

All you need is join them together. I repeated your queries as [Common Table Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175972.aspx) (CTE) and joined them.

```
WITH
CTE_Query1
AS
(
    SELECT 
        T3.AcctCode, T3.AcctName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN T0.TaxDate BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'
                 THEN T1.Debit - T1.Credit 
                 ELSE 0 END)* -1 AS [Balance],
        SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit)* -1  AS [YTD Balance],
        (CASE WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '611110' AND '612000'
           THEN 1 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '541100' AND '541950'
           THEN 2 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '542100' AND '542700'
           THEN 3 WHEN T3.AcctCode = '543100'
           THEN 4 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '511100' AND '511950'
           THEN 5 WHEN T3.AcctCode BETWEEN '512100' AND '512995'
           THEN 6 WHEN T3.AcctCode = '513100'
           THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) AS [Group]
    FROM 
        OJDT T0
    INNER JOIN 
        JDT1 T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId]
    INNER JOIN 
        OACT T2 ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode]
    INNER JOIN 
        OACT T3 ON T3.[AcctCode] = T2.[FatherNum]
    WHERE 
        T0.TaxDate BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-12-31'     
        AND T2.GroupMask IN(5,6)
    GROUP BY 
        T3.AcctCode, T3.AcctName
)
,CTE_Query2
AS
(
    SELECT 
        T1.FatherNum, SUM(T0.CredLTotal) AS [Budget]
    FROM 
        OBGT T0
    LEFT JOIN 
        OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
    WHERE 
        T1.GroupMask IN (5, 6) 
        AND (T1.FatherNum BETWEEN '511100' AND '612000') 
        AND YEAR(T0.FinancYear) = 2015 
    GROUP BY 
        T1.FatherNum
)
SELECT *
FROM
    CTE_Query1
    INNER JOIN CTE_Query2 ON CTE_Query2.FatherNum = CTE_Query1.AcctCode
;
```

Comment: Nice. Just needed to change INNER JOIN CTE_Query2 ON CTE_Query2.FatherNum = CTE_Query1.AcctCode to a left join.